# Как пролистать Panel через AutoScroll кнопкой?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, как при нажатии на кнопку пролистать Panel через AutoScroll, таким образом, чтобы пролистывание уходило в самый конец Panel

Например в одной части панели 4 кнопки `button` на другой невидимой части тоже 4 кнопки, и нужно при нажатии на кнопку `>>` переместить невидимую часть панели, чтобы отобразить дополнительное управление (пролистать AutoScroll в самый конец одним нажатием на `>>`).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужен кусочек кода для `> button >`, который может передвинуть ползунок на AutoScroll в конец всей Panel

Comment: Чтобы промотать в конец, в обработчике кнопки напишите `panel.HorizontalScroll.Value = panel.HorizontalScroll.Maximum;`

Comment: Спасибо, но если `AutoScroll` сделать невидимым - `False` то прокрутка не работает, не проматывает...

Comment: Вы спросили про автоскролл, вы получили ответ (можете его оформить и принять). Раз уж вы решили не использовать автоскролл, тогда задайте новый вопрос.